# how to connect two tables in visual foxpro

Tags: join, visual-foxpro

I'm using visual foxpro 6.0. I want to join 2 tables:

#### table1

```
studnum studname   sec   course
  01      franz    1a    bsct
```

#### table2

```
studnum studname   sec   course
  02      simon    1b    bsct
```

I want it  to be like this:

#### table3

```
studnum studname   sec   course
  01      franz    1a    bsct
  02      simon    1b    bsct
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT studnum, studname, sec, course  ;
  FROM table1 ;
UNION ALL ;
SELECT studnum, studname, sec, course  ;
  FROM table2 ;
INTO CURSOR Table3
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several way to do this.

From the command window or you program file(.prg)

```
*Since the table structures are the same
SELECT table1
APPEND FROM table2
```

or

```
*using a SQL statement
 INSERT INTO table1 (studnum, studname, sec, course) ;
    SELECT studnum, studname, sec, course  ;
       FROM table2  
      *optional where or order by condition
```